# Bandwidth of LCR circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

I'm trying to derive the expression of half-power bandwidth of LCR circuit but I'm struck.

[image]

---

My approach:

Let resonance frequency $ω_0 = \dfrac 1{LC}$ and peak voltage at resonance be $V = IR$ where $I$  is the peak current.

At half-power:

Peak current $= \frac I{\sqrt2} $

Peak voltage $V= \dfrac I{\sqrt 2 }\sqrt{R^2+(ωL - \dfrac 1{ωC})^2}$

Equating the expressions for $V$ and squaring, I get:

$\pm R = ωL - \dfrac 1{ωC}$

And solving the quadratic gives

$ω = \frac{\pm RC \pm \sqrt{R^2C^2+4LC}}{2LC}$

---

Now half power bandwidth $Δω = \frac RL$ and the twice the difference of $ω$ and $ω_0$ should give me the bandwidth but I'm not getting this from $2(ω_0-ω)$.

Someone please help :)

Comment: The question is not clear. Also, you mess up with $\pm$, since it appears in two different place, but you seem to treat it as $+$ corresponds to $+$ and $-$ to $-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might look it, the graph is not symmetrical about the resonant frequency $\omega_0$ thus, $(\omega_0-\omega_{\text{half power,lower}})\ne (\omega_{\text{half power,upper}} - \omega_0)$.

As the $Q$ value of the circuit increases the approximation $(\omega_0-\omega_{\text{half power,lower}})\approx (\omega_{\text{half power,upper}} - \omega_0)$ gets better.

For example look at $\omega_{\text{half power,upper}} - \omega_0 = \dfrac{R}{2L}+ \sqrt{\left( \dfrac{R}{2L}\right)^2+\dfrac{1}{LC}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$.

Note that as $R$ is made smaller and smaller, ($Q$ becoming larger and larger), the middle square root term tends to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$ and $\omega_{\text{half power,upper}}$ tends to $\dfrac{R}{2L}$.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/itg1ulg5cf) and the positive values of $ω$ are:

$ω_1 = \frac{RC + \sqrt{R^2C^2+4LC}}{2LC}$

$ω_2 = \frac{- RC + \sqrt{R^2C^2+4LC}}{2LC}$

It seems finding the difference between $ω$ and $ω_0$ is difficult but the bandwidth can be also found as:

$ω_1-ω_2 = \dfrac RL$